# Need help creating a query with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure and data:

```
ID_A | ID_B
 A      1
 A      2
 B      1
 B      2
 C      1
 C      3
 D      1
 D      2
 D      3
```

I need to find the different sets of B that exist for the give A id's. In the example the result would be:

1. 1,2
2. 1,3
3. 1,2,3

If I can get the counting too that would be great:

1. 1,2 [2]
2. 1,3 [1]
3. 1,2,3 [1]

I hope the question is clear enought. Thanks!

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Do you have some SQL you're working with and it's not working? See, we're not here to write your software for you, we're here to help each other debug things we're stuck on.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: maybe you're not here to write software for others but in the past I requested help like this and I got it. I don't know where to start with the query so I haven't tryed anything but scratching my head. Talking in the name of all the other SO users is maybe too much ...

Comment: By asking a question like this, you are not abiding by the rules and regulations set forth by this community. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) please. Please note the **do your homework** section.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: if I need help to understand how SO works I will ask you, thanks. Bytheway I've been involved with SO about 3 years before you.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: and let me tell you that there is just one complain (yours) and the answer is here so looks like it was a valid question for others ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d2bc/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID_A char(1),
  ID_B int
)

insert into YourTable values
( 'A',      1),
( 'A',      2),
( 'B',      1),
( 'B',      2),
( 'C',      1),
( 'C',      3),
( 'D',      1),
( 'D',      2),
( 'D',      3)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T.ID_B,
       count(*) as C
from
  (
  select T1.ID_A,
         (
         select ','+cast(T2.ID_B as varchar(10))
         from YourTable as T2
         where T2.ID_A = T1.ID_A
         order by T2.ID_B
         for xml path(''), type
         ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as ID_B
  from YourTable as T1
  group by T1.ID_A
  ) as T
group by T.ID_B
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d2bc/1/0)**:

```
|  ID_B | C |
-------------
|   1,2 | 2 |
| 1,2,3 | 1 |
|   1,3 | 1 |
```

Comment: Whoao, amazing! I had not been able to end with something like that even with two lifes :D Thanks a lot.